# Динамические многомерные массивы

Tags: c++, xcode

Помогите решить проблему с инициализацией многомерных массивов. Xcode выдает ошибку `thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` в функции `fillarray`в строке `array[i][j] = LOW + rand() / (HIGH - LOW);`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> T**givemem(T**, int, int);
template <typename T> T**freemem(T**, int);
template <typename T> T**fillarray(T**, int, int, int, int);
template <typename T> T**printarray(T**, int, int);
template <typename T> T**product(T**, T**, T**, int, int, int);

template <typename T> T**givemem(T** array, int string, int column){
    array = new T * [string];
    for (int i = 0; i < string; i++){
        array[i] = new T [column];
    }
    return array;
}
template <typename T> T**freemem(T** array, int string){
    for (int i = 0; i < string; i++){
        delete [] array[i];
    }
    delete [] array;
    return 0;
}
template <typename T> T**fillarray(T** array, int str, int col, int HIGH, int LOW){
    for (int i = 0; i < str; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            array[i][j] = LOW + rand() / (HIGH - LOW);
        }
    }
    return array;
}
template <typename T> T**printarray(T** array, int str, int col){
    for (int i = 0; i < str; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            cout<< setw(4) << array[i][j];
        }
    }
    return array;
}
template <typename T> T**product(T** array_a, T** array_b, T** array_c, int str_a, int stb_a, int stb_b){
    for (int i = 0; i < str_a; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < stb_b; j++){
            array_c[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k=0; k<stb_a; k++){
                array_c+=array_a[i][k]*array_b[k][j];
            }

        }
    }
}

int main(){
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int string_a, column_a, string_b, column_b, HIGH = 15, LOW = -10;
    cin >> string_a >> column_a;
    cin >> string_b >> column_b;
    int **array_a, **array_b, **array_c;
    givemem(array_a, string_a, column_a);
    givemem(array_b, string_b, column_b);
    givemem(array_c, string_a, column_b);
    fillarray(array_a, string_a, column_a, HIGH, LOW);
    fillarray(array_b, string_b, column_b, HIGH, LOW);
    cout<<"\n\n\n";
    printarray(array_a, string_a, column_a);
    cout<<"\n\n\n";
    printarray(array_b, string_b, column_b);
    product(array_a, array_b, array_c, string_a, column_a, column_b);
    cout<<"\n\n\n";
    printarray(array_c, string_a, column_b);
    freemem(array_a, string_a);
    freemem(array_b, string_b);
    freemem(array_c, string_a);
}
```

Comment: Рискну предположить, что причина в том, что выделяете вы память из нескольких кусков, а работаете с ней как будто она единым куском в памяти лежит. Зачем вам цикл с new при выделении, если можно написать что-то типа "array = new T [column * string];". И вместо string тут больше подходит слово row.

Comment: Указатель в `givemem` передается по значению. Либо передавайте по ссылке, либо передавайте его адрес и разъименовывайте внутри, либо просто пишите `array_a = givemem(...)`, поскольку все равно возвращаете этот указатель. Кстати, в таком случае аргументы givemem() можно сократить до `givemem(int n_rows, int n_columns)`, соответственно первой строкой добавить там определение указателя `T **array = new T * [n_rows];`, который и возвращаете.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самая главная проблема, на чем, собственно, все и валится - `givemem` получает `array_a` по значению, но и это было бы полбеды, но вы не используете возвращаемое значение! Результат: память выделяется, присваивается *копии* `array_a`, после выхода из функции память потеряна. Нужно либо передавать как `T**& array_a`, либо присваивать `array_a = givemem(...`.

Кроме написанного @int3, добавлю также, что раз уж вы работаете не только с квадратными матрицами (иначе зачем 2 размера?), то надо бы проверять, можно ли их умножать друг на друга - иначе и тут вас ждут сюрпризы с выходом за пределы диапазона...

И еще - хотя формально имя `string` можно использовать как параметр количества строк, во-первых, это очень распространенный тип в C++, так что его применение "всуе" будет сбивать с толку, если не конфликтовать позже с типом... ну и просто строка в матрице - это не `string`, это `row`...

Answer (score 0):

Код ужасен.
Могу посоветовать следующее:

Сменить прототипы:

```
template <typename T> T **givemem(int, int);
template <typename T> void freemem(T**, int);
template <typename T> void fillarray(T**, int, int, int, int);
template <typename T> void printarray(const T**, int, int);
template <typename T> void product(const T**, const T**, T**, int, int, int);
```

Переделать выделение памяти:

```
template <typename T> T** givemem(int string, int column){
    T** array = new T * [string];
    for (int i = 0; i < string; i++){
        array[i] = new T [column];
    }
    return array;
}
```

Убрать `return` из остальных функций.

Заменить

```
array[i][j] = LOW + rand() / (HIGH - LOW);
```

на

```
array[i][j] = LOW + rand() % (HIGH - LOW); /// для дробных типов лучше использоать LOW + static_cast<T>(rand()) / RAND_MAX * (HIGH - LOW)
```

Заменить

```
array_c+=array_a[i][k]*array_b[k][j];
```

на

```
array_c[i][j] += array_a[i][k] * array_b[k][j];
```

Больше не вглядывался